# add border outside image slide show

Tags: html, css, slideshow

I am putting together a slideshow for a CMS, this slideshow has some tolerance for a range of image dimensions. Unfortunately I am unable to wrap all the images in a border.

See the image to better understand the problem.

[image]

Comment: [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome to SO. When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: we need to see your code. [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [bin](http://jsbin.com/) will be the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this, hope this will work for you.

```css
.slider_container {
  position: relative;
}
.slider_container img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.slider_container .border_box {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider_container">

  <img src="http://www.electricprism.com/aeron/slideshow/images/1.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="border_box"></div>

</div>
```